# Correlation between GitLab and system crashes?

Tags: debian, crash, gitlab

Continuing from [Server crashing for not so obvious reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362807/server-crashing-for-not-so-obvious-reasons/).

## Short overview of what happened

My server (running Debian) has crashed very often.
Everything would work fine until noticable lag sets in. There are oops messages in the `dmesg` logs. They do not appear to be fatal but sometimes the server simply becomes unresponsive. The management interface from the node the server runs on (it's virtualized) says that during this time [when it's unresponsive] the CPU load goes haywire.

## So...

I have talked with friend of mine (who maintains multiple servers) and he said that he is experiencing this problem as well. But only on the server running GitLab CE.
I have GitLab CE (installed from `deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/debian/ jessie main`). So I tried stopping the GitLab services.

Since I stopped all GitLab processes the problem is gone. Everything running perfectly fine.

What do I do wrong? Are there some configuration traps that can crash my server without leaving a trace of information? The rcu_shed stall messages still appear but the server is not crashing anymore.

Comment: Probably I/O related? When deploying? Have you done more specific tests?

Comment: No specific tests. I don't know which... Once I changed the I/O scheduler to `noop` but only temporary and it crashed either way.

Comment: With a recent kernel in vmware, *I think* the default is `noop` nowadays.

Comment: With Debian 8 `cfg` is the default. At least on my maching. Do you think it is a problem with the scheduler? What can I try to test this?

Comment: The scheduler wont be my first suspicion. I would monitor I/O vs CPU usage over time.

Comment: How do I monitor I/O?

Comment: To have nice graphs over time - snmpd + MRTG for a single server / Cacti for several servers -- those solutions are pretty well simple to set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60248/discussion-between-martin-b-and-rui-f-ribeiro).